# Radiobutton Validation Using Correct Operator

Tags: c#, radio-button

### Background

I'm trying to validate a group of 5 radiobuttons by showing a messagebox if none are selected.

### My code

```
...
else if (assetsRb.Checked == false || fabricRb.Checked == false || fireRb.Checked == false || hsRb.Checked == false || partMRb.Checked == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Assessment type.");
                    }
...
```

### Question

I don't understand why this isn't working and always returns true, displaying the messagebox, even when radioboxes are checked?

Comment: No, it's simple the wrong operator. You wanted to show the message if none are checked, but you show it if any is not checked because of the or-operator

Comment: First, you have yo use "&&" instead of "||".
Second, one of radiobuttons must always be selected - that's how radiobuttons work and making them all unselected is misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the `&&` operator.

```
...
else if (assetsRb.Checked == false && fabricRb.Checked == false && fireRb.Checked == false && hsRb.Checked == false && partMRb.Checked == false)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Please Select Assessment type.");
                    }
...
```